# Вывод данных ForeignKey в шаблон

Tags: django

Есть 2 модели:

```
class shops_cafe(models.Model):
    cafe_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name="Название", help_text="Название")
    cafe_status = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name="Статус", blank=True, default=None)
    cafe_like = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Лайки", null=True, blank=True)
    cafe_added = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, verbose_name="Добавил", null=True, blank=True)
    cafe_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cafe_logo', blank=False, null=False, default='cafe_logo/default_logo.jpg', verbose_name="Логотип", help_text="Логотип")
    cafe_info = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Краткое описание", help_text="Краткое описание")
    cafe_web = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Веб-сайт", help_text="Веб-сайт")
    cafe_adres = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name="Адрес", help_text="Адрес", null=True, blank=True)
    cafe_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Номер телефона", help_text="Номер телефона")

    class Meta():
        db_table = "Кафе/рестораны"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cafe_name
```

и

```
class shops_cafe_com(models.Model):
    shc_create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), verbose_name="Дата создания")
    shc_text = models.TextField(max_length=3000, verbose_name="Текст", help_text="Максимальная длина")
    shc_cafe = models.ForeignKey(shops_cafe, verbose_name="Кафе/ресторан")
    shc_create_name = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, verbose_name="Добавил")

    class Meta():
        db_table = "Кафе/рестораны_комментарии"
```

как видно коменты- дочерняя , shops_cafe - родительская.

В view организую все через пагинатор и в шаблон вывожу список (for...) из shops_cafe:

```
def ...(request, page_number=1):
...
all_cafe = shops_cafe.objects.filter(cafe_status="1").order_by('-cafe_like')
current_page = Paginator(all_cafe, 3)
args['cafes'] = current_page.page(page_number)
return render_to_response("shops.html", args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

соответственно в шаблоне уже , например `{{ cafe.cafe_name }}` и т.д.

**Вопрос:** как мне вывести данные из дочерней модели? Т.е. требуется рядом с `{{ cafe.cafe_name }}` вывести *кол-во комментариев* из shops_cafe_com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count

all_cafe = shops_cafe.objects.filter(
    cafe_status="1"
).annotate(shc_count=Count('shops_cafe_com')).order_by('-cafe_like')
```

В шаблоне: `{{ cafe.shc_count }}`. [Аггрегация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: Спасибо. Так же работает : (не меняя view) в шаблоне {{ cafe.shops_cafe_com_set.count }}

Comment: @FlatOMG Если использовать `{{ cafe.shops_cafe_com_set.count }}`, то для каждого `cafe` из `all_cafe` будет выполнятся SQL-запрос. Если использовать аннотации, то будет выполнятся 1 запрос. Но это уже оптимизация.